# Multi-level menu in ASP.NET CORE ANGULAR 5.x

Tags: angular, typescript, aspnetboilerplate

I am working with nested menu with AppMenuItem, but not more than one nested sub-menu is working (collapsed) like its parent.
Here is my menu structure (app-navigation.service.ts):

```
    getMenu(): AppMenu {
    return new AppMenu('MainMenu', 'MainMenu', [
        new AppMenuItem('Dashboard', 'Pages.Administration.Host.Dashboard', 'flaticon-line-graph', '/app/admin/hostDashboard'),
        new AppMenuItem('Dashboard', 'Pages.Tenant.Dashboard', 'flaticon-line-graph', '/app/main/dashboard'),
        new AppMenuItem('Tenants', 'Pages.Tenants', 'flaticon-list-3', '/app/admin/tenants'),


        new AppMenuItem('MasterPlan', 'Pages.Tenant.MasterPlan', '  flaticon-line-graph', '', [
            new AppMenuItem('Project', 'Pages.Tenant.MasterProject', 'flaticon-line-graph', '', [
                new AppMenuItem('MasterDepartment', 'Pages.Tenant.MasterDepartment', 'flaticon-line-graph', ''),
            ]),
        ]),
    ])
}
```

Comment: What is the AppMenuItem? How do you render your menu? Where is angular here?

Comment: I am using aspnetboilerplate with angular. https://aspnetzero.com/

Comment: `MasterDepartment` should have a link, not `''`.

Comment: @aaron there is no problem with the code, it's just not showing as expected. I think there is a problem with the sidebar html file.

Comment: Did you try that? Show a screenshot.

Comment: The items under the project menu item (department, project, and account) don't indent and don't collapsed like MasterPlan menu. [imgur.com/a/LrLcC](https://imgur.com/a/LrLcC)

Comment: Fixed in v5.0.5: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=25539

Comment: this has been fixed in this commit => https://github.com/aspnetzero/aspnet-zero-core/commit/51f391e58ce515d5dca0392d0f77d1e06764fe6c . If you have access to the AspNet Zero repository you can see the changes otherwise try to fix it in angular/src/app/shared/layout/nav/side-bar-menu.component.html